# Is adding to a set O(n)?

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, set

Since sets can only have unique values does this mean every time you add an element to a set it has to check whether it is equal to every element there and is hence O(n)?

Since this would make them much slower than arrayLists if this is the case, is the only time you should ever actually use them is when making sure your elements are all unique or is there any other advantage of them?

Comment: Which language and which container? std::set has an insert method which takes O(log(size())).

Comment: This depends on the implementation of a `set`. An `std::set` in C++ is typically implemented as a red-black tree and guarantees an insert complexity of O(log(n)) ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)).

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the Set. In Java per example, adding an element to an HashSet is `O(1)`(assuming your hash function distributes uniformely your elements). However in a TreeSet it's `O(log(n))`

Comment: You can view the implementing classes here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This depends on the implementation of a `set`.

### C++

An `std::set` in C++ is typically implemented as a red-black tree and guarantees an insert complexity of O(log(n)) ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)).

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity.

C++11's `std::unordered_set` has an insert complexity of O(1) ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)).

> Unordered set is an associative container that contains set of unique objects of type Key. Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time complexity.

### JAVA

In Java, adding an element to a `HashSet` is O(1). From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets

Inserting an element into a `TreeSet` is O(log(n)).

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

All classes implementing `Set` can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

### Conclusion

Adding to a `set` is, in most cases, not slower than adding to an `ArrayList` or `std::vector`. However, a `set` does not necessarily keep items in the order in which they are inserted. Also, accessing some *Nth* element of a set has a worse complexity than the same operation on an `ArrayList` or `std::vector`. Each has their advantages and disadvantages and should be used accordingly.

Comment: adding to a java HashSet is _amortized_ O(1)

Answer (score 3):

You tagged this Java as well as C++, so I'll answer for both:

In C++ `std::set` is an ordered container, likely implemented as a tree. Regardless of implementation adding to a set and checking whether an element in a set are guaranteed to be O(log n). For `std::unordered_set`, which is new in C++11, those operations are O(1) (given a proper hashing function).

In Java `java.util.Set` is an interface that can have many different classes who implement them. The complexities of the operations are up to those classes. The most commonly used sets are `TreeSet` and `HashSet`. The operations on the former are O(log n) and for the latter they're O(1) (again, giving a proper hashing function).

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Different languages provide different implementations. Even java has 2 different sets: A TreeSet and a HashSet. Adding is a TreeSet is O(logn), since the elements are already in an order.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ `std::set` is normally implemented as a black-and-red tree. This means that adding to it will be O(log n).

A C++ `std::unordered_set` insertion is implemented as a hash-table so insertion is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You forget that a set may not be a bulk list of elements; it can be arranged (and it indeed is) in such a way that searches are much faster than `O(N)`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Implementations

Answer (score 0):

in cpp, sets are typically implemented as binary search trees. with that being said, inserting would require O(log(N)) time complexity. when it comes to unique key, u can try hash_map in cpp, which has a constant time complexity when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

## Time complexity: Wrapper Classes vs Primitives.

- When the value changes, especially multiple times, primitives give better time.

Example:

```
   int counter = 0; 
     while (x>y){ 
     counter++; 
     }
```

is much faster than:

```
Integer counter = 0; 
 while (x>y){ 
 counter++; 
 }
```

- When the value remains the same, wrapper classes give better time since only a pointer to the wrapper class is passed to the algorithm. It comes handy in defining parameters of methods that do not change their value.

Example:

```
 public int sum (Integer one, Integer two, Integer three){ 
 int sum = one+two+three; 
 return sum; 
 }
```

is faster than

```
public int sum (int one, int two, int three){ 
 int sum = one+two+three;
 return sum; 
 }
```

The values that are passed to the methods could be primitive, the important thing is the definition of the parameters of the method itself, that is to say:

```
 public int sum (Integer one, Integer two, Integer three){ 
 int sum = one+two+three;                                               
 return sum; 
 } 

 int a = 1; int b = 2; int c = 3;                                       

 public int sum (a, b, c){ 
 int sum = a+b+c; 
 return sum; 
 }
```

The cumulative effect of using wrapper classes as described above could significantly improve the performance of a program.

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated, sets are usually either trees O(logn) or hash tables O(1). However, there is one thing you can be sure about: **No sane map implementation would have O(n) behaviour.**

Comment: be careful how assertive you are about that last comment, specialized situations can call for specialized implementations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html